# NewsML: sample examples of NewsML

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am studying about the `NewsML`. Is there any java tutorials or sample applications for NewsML?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at the [newsML-toolkit manual](http://newsml-toolkit.sourceforge.net/newsml-toolkit-manual.html) this shows how to use the newsML-toolkit classes to read and write NewsML messages. You can download the java classes from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/p/newsml-toolkit). However the toolkit is kinda old and uses some outdated dependencies like an old xerces version. For a starting point this is good enough but when you want to use NewsML message processing in an application already defining a newer xerces version this will not work so easily.

I needed it for a project where we only need to read NewsML messages and show them on a webpage. In the end it was the easiest solution to use an XML Parser and find the notes with XPath instead of using the newsML-toolkit project.